# Stop a process from exiting

Tags: macos, memory-leaks

I am currently using the leaks command line utility on Mac OS X. It requires an active process which is a pain with a command line utility. Is there a way to launch a process and on exit freeze it (so it stays running) so leaks can work like the following

> leaks executable_binary_name

instead of

> leaks currently_running_process_name_or_pid

as the latter is a pain to use with a command line application that doesn't normally just remain open. I assume the program has to run through so leaks can observe the used memory and so I'd have to freeze it on exit.

**Part of man page dealing with process**

> leaks requires one parameter -- either the **process** ID or executable
>   name
>        of the **process** to examine.  It also takes several arguments for modifying
>        its behavior.

Answer (score 0):

Use `iprofiler` ([manpage](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Darwin/Reference/ManPages/man1/iprofiler.1.html)) instead.  It's the command line equivalent of *Instruments* and allows an executable or process ID to be specified.

Something like:

```
$ iprofiler -leaks -d $HOME/tmp executable [args]
```

You can even pass arguments to `executable`, if it accepts them.

The `-d` option specifies where the output `.dtps` file will be written to, which can be loaded into *Instruments* for examination.

Comment: The issue with that, is unlike leaks, it writes to a file.